# Regex to check if a string contains only letters(lower/caps), numbers and some special characters

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

A string that I obtain using `read`form user can contain:

- letters
- numbers
- `_`

For another string the rules are the same as above plus:

- starts only with letters

I'm starting from this:

```
if [[ $A = [a-z]* ]]
```

but it checks to see if the string start with lowercase letters,

Comment: try putting a $ at the end, to indicate the end of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case this should work:

```
if [[ $A = \w+ ]]
```

`\w` mathches a "word" character, which includes the underscore. It may recognize some unicode strings which may be invalid so `[A-Za-z0-9\\_]` may work better than `\w` for you.

For the second try:

```
if [[ $A = ^[A-Za-z]\w+ ]]
```